# Why is one fold tail-recursive and the other one is not?

Tags: sml, tail-recursion, smlnj

```
fun fold1 f acc lst =
    case lst of
         [] => acc
       | hd::tl => fold1 f (f (acc,hd)) tl

fun fold2 f acc lst =
    case lst of
         [] => acc
       | hd::tl => f (fold2 f acc tl, hd)
```

Why first one is tail-recursive and the other is not?

I think both of them are tail-recursive.

Comment: Could you explain *why* you think both of them are tail-recursive?

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of how `fold2` has `f` in "tail position", but that is not recursive.

Comment: You should adopt one answer as accepted if your problem is solved. If you still feel confused, comment below the answers.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is tail-recursive because the recursive call (to `fold1`) appears at the end of the function body (it forms the "tail"):

```
fold1 f (f (acc,hd)) tl
```

calls `f (acc,hd)` first, then passes the result (along with `f` and `tl`) to `fold1`. This is the last thing the function does; the result of the recursive `fold1` call is passed through to our caller.

---

The second one is not tail-recursive because the recursive call (to `foldl2`) is not the last thing the function does:

```
f (fold2 f acc tl, hd)
```

calls `fold2 f acc tl` first, then makes a tuple from the result and `hd`, then passes that tuple to `f`.

There are two things that happen after the recursive `fold2` call: Tuple construction (`(..., hd)`) and another function call (`f ...`). In particular, the result of calling `fold2` is not passed straight through to our caller. That's why this code is not tail-recursive.

Answer (score 0):

> Why first one is tail-recursive and the other is not?

Given a [definition of *tail-recursive*](http://wiki.c2.com/?TailRecursion),

> A function call is said to be tail recursive if there is nothing to do after the function returns except return its value.

In the first function,

```
fun fold1 f acc lst =
    case lst of
         [] => acc
       | hd::tl => fold1 f (f (acc,hd)) tl
```

all other computation (`f (acc, hd)`) is performed as an argument to `fold1`, meaning *there is nothing to do after the function returns except return its value*.

In the second function,

```
fun fold2 f acc lst =
    case lst of
         [] => acc
       | hd::tl => f (fold2 f acc tl, hd)
```

all other computation (`f (..., hd)`) is performed *after* `fold2 f acc tl` has executed, meaning *there **is** something to do after the function returns*, namely compute `f (..., hd)`.

Tail-recursive functions have the defining characteristic that the outermost expression of its recursive function body is a call to itself. If anything else is computed in the function, it should happen *before* this call is made, e.g. as a function argument, or in a let-binding.

For example, the following refactoring of `fold1` is also tail-recursive:

```
fun fold1 f acc0 [] = acc0
  | fold1 f acc0 (x::xs) =
    let val acc1 = f (acc0, x)
    in fold1 f acc1 xs
    end
```

and the following refactoring of `fold2` isn't:

```
fun fold2 f acc0 [] = acc0
  | fold2 f acc0 (x::xs) =
    let val acc1 = fold2 f acc0 xs
    in f (acc1, x)
    end
```

Because there is nothing else to do after `fold1 f acc1 xs`, the context of the function call (the stack frame) can safely be discarded. A simpler example of non-tail-recursive vs. tail-recursive are:

```
fun length [] = 0
  | length (_::xs) = 1 + length xs

fun length xs =
    let fun go [] count = count
          | go (_::ys) count = go ys (1 + count)
    in go xs 0
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

#### If it is a tail recursion, it must locate at tail position. Arguments are not tail position.

---

In your case:

```
case lst of
     [] => e1
   | hd::tl => e2
```

`e1` and `e2` are both tail case, because there are no other **expressions** after evaluating the **value** of the two **expression**(IOW, they locate at tail position). That's why `fold1` is tail recursion.

As for `f (fold2 f acc tl, hd)`, `f(...)` do locate at tail position. But `fold2` here is not at tail position, because after evaluating its **value**, you still need to invoke `f`. So `f` is tail recursion while `fold2` is not.